# Is this wrong expression to convert checkbox array values to string?

Tags: php, database

```
$permission=implodes(',', $_POST["permission"]);
```

As i get fatel error Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function implodes() when i am trying to insert the form values in my database. help much appreciated

Comment: implode(glue,peices) not implodes()

Comment: it worked thanks for the spot

Answer (score 3):

`implodes` should be `implode`.

```
$permission=implode(',', $_POST["permission"]);
```

Additionally, because you're taking your input from a $_POST, I suspect you actually want `explode`:

```
$permission=explode(',', $_POST["permission"]);
```

`implode` combines array to a string, like `implode(',',array(1,2,3))` would output the string, `"1,2,3"`.

And `explode` does the reverse. It would take `explode(',','1,2,3')` would output the list, `[1,2,3]`